# File is always empty after submiting FileField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, filefield

I have a form where I need to gather some text data and a file.After submiting, the textFields are fine, but the FileField seems to be empty.

The validator FileRequired claims that the field is empty, and if I remove it it is indeed NoneType.

Form Class:

```py
from wtforms import Form, StringField,validators,SubmitField,DateField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired,FileAllowed
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask import flash
import baseDatos

class  AnadirForm(FlaskForm):
    id=StringField('id')
    nombre=StringField('nombre',[validators.InputRequired()])
    volumen=StringField('volumen',[validators.InputRequired()])
    fecha= DateField('fecha',[validators.InputRequired()])
    file = FileField('Introduce Gcode',validators=[FileRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

Rendering Class:

```py
@app.route("/",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    primeraForm=AnadirForm(request.form)


    if(primeraForm.validate_on_submit()):
        print(primeraForm.file.data)
```

HTML:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                {{form.id(class="form-control",placeholder="Id")}}
            </div>
            <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                {{form.nombre(class="form-control",placeholder="Nombre")}}
            </div>

            <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                {{form.volumen(class="form-control",placeholder="Volumen")}}
            </div>
            <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                {{form.fecha(class="form-control",placeholder="Fecha")}}
            </div>
             <div>
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                {{form.file(placeholder="File")}}
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
        </div>
        </form>
```

I cannot manage to access the file data(which I will have to store later, but after I manage to get the file)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
form = AnadirForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

or:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':        
    file = request.files['file_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was replacing `FileField()` with `MultipleFileField()` and then adjusting the data processing, as you get a list of files and not just a file.

I have no idea, where this error came from and it seems totally strange to me, as FileField worked for me in another case, although there was no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this code once:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
            
            {{form.id(class="form-control",placeholder="Id")}}
        </div>
        <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
            {{form.nombre(class="form-control",placeholder="Nombre")}}
        </div>

        <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
            {{form.volumen(class="form-control",placeholder="Volumen")}}
        </div>
        <div class="hueco col-xs-7">
            {{form.fecha(class="form-control",placeholder="Fecha")}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{form.file(placeholder="File")}}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
    </div>
</form>
```